# Pinging own machine returns an IPv6 address instead of IPv4

Tags: dhcp, ip-address, ping, ipv6

When I ping my own machine I get an IPv6 address:

```
Reply from fe80::1004:p8f0:9e40:a42c%10: time<1ms
Reply from fe80::1004:p8f0:9e40:a42c%10: time<1ms
```

I used to get the IPv4 address (eg. 192.168.1.5) from the router.

Why has it changed?

Comment: What is your machine?

Comment: @djerry: just a Win7 Pro machine connected wirelessly to the router.

Comment: Relevant: http://superuser.com/questions/285599/pinging-localhost-versus-pinging-127-0-0-1

Comment: Are you pinging the machine by name or IP?

Comment: @CraigJ: djerry is asked what you are pinging. The address you get is determined by the name resolution method. If it is `localhost`, then it is likely to return IPv6 every time.

Comment: @NickWhaley: I am pinging my machine's Windows computer name or IP address. Both produce these results. If you have downvoted the question please reverse it. I don't see what is wrong with the question.

Comment: @CraigJ, ping will ping whatever it is given. This question has nothing to do with ping and has everything to do with how the given name is resolved. Please tell us what name is being resolved incorrectly or in an unexpected way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem was solved by running `ipconfig /flushdns` from the command prompt.

Comment: @ekaj: or link to the serverfault question, as the answer on there is what helps the OP.

Answer (score 8):

This could be due to caching or the DNS. On a [Windows Server 2008 issue on Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/questions/47303/ping-returns-an-ipv6-address) they suggest:

> If they are resolving to IPv6 they might be cached or have ipv6
>   addresses registered in DNS.

You can also add a -4 to the ping:

> ping example.com -4

Comment: When I use the `-4` I get the IPv4 address. Any reason it is defaulting to IPv6 instead of IPv4?

Comment: @CraigJ: On Windows, IPv6 is always preferred over IPv4.